# How to intercept keystrokes from within the field editor of an NSTextField?

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, appkit, nsresponder

## Intro

When my custom `NSTextField` is in "text editing mode" and the `field editor` has been placed in front of it as `firstResponder` I no longer get the keystrokes through `NSTextField.keyDown(...)`. I understand that the keystrokes are now being routed through the `field editor`. Most online recommendations are to override the following method within the delegate of the custom `NSTextField`:

```
control(_:textView:doCommandBySelector:)
```

I have indeed overridden this method but it doesn't seem to get called? See code below:

```
class FocusDelegate: NSObject, NSTextFieldDelegate{

    func control(control: NSControl, textView: NSTextView, doCommandBySelector commandSelector: Selector) -> Bool {

        println("FocusDelegate")
        if commandSelector == Selector("cancelOperation:"){
            println("cancelOperation")
            control.abortEditing()
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

The only other thing I do is set the delegate of my custom `NSTextField` to an instance of the class above. I have also tried placing the method above directly into the custom `NSTextField` class - it doesn't cause any errors but it also doesn't get called.

## Questions

1. What am I missing above in getting the delegate call to work?
2. Other than creating my own custom field editor is this the only way? Can the `textDidChange(notification: NSNotification)` not be interrogated to yield the keys pressed?
3. In using the `control(_:textView:doCommandBySelector:)` delegate method, how do I trap the pressing of keys that do **NOT** have standard key bindings. In particular, I want to intercept the key combination "shift+enter" which does not map to any standard selector. (Implied Question: can you only map to standard key-action methods in NSResponder?)

Comment: When you say formula editor, do you mean field editor?

Comment: @JWWalker LOL, was confusing what I am using it for with its official name! Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Do you need to use the underscore (`_`) in your function's signature to get it to match? The docs have `func control(_ control: NSControl, textView textView: NSTextView, doCommandBySelector command: Selector)`. If you use that signature, does it get called?

Comment: @KenThomases I think the underscore is a red-herring. The code above was auto-completed by Xcode. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I have achieved greater clarity with regard to the workings of `NSTextField` its delegates and its fieldEditor and its delegates. Yes, each one has its own delegate and the `NSTextField` is automatically set up as the delegate of the `fieldEditor`.

I was adding a delegate to the host `NSTextField`. This will *NOT* get called when the `fieldEditor` is `firstResponder`, which was what I was concerned with. This is also not the important delegate for the scenario above.

What appears to be useful is making the `NSTextField` conform to the `NSTextViewDelegate` protocol and specifically overriding the method:

```
 func textView(textView: NSTextView, shouldChangeTextInRange affectedCharRange: NSRange, replacementString: String) -> Bool
```

to trap various keypresses.

The notification in `textDidChange(notification: NSNotification)` is not of use in this scenario because it is reported *AFTER* the keypress.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not apply for arrow keys.

Answer (score 1):

Intercepting pressed keys in `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementString:` is not ideal because that is called rather late, and is also called when the user pastes from the clipboard, for instance.

A probably cleaner way is to intercept `textView:doCommandBySelector:`, which gets called for all kinds of special keys such as tab, cursor, return and enter, for which you'll then get specific selectors that let you determine which special key was invoked.

For some keys, however, such as Return (`CR`) and Enter (`ETX`), you can't tell them apart, because both use the same "insertNewline:" selector.

In this case, you can check whether the currently handled event is a keydown event, and if so, check which key it was.

Here's a quick test code that lets you monitor the selector names and the involved keycode:

```
-(BOOL)textView:(NSTextView *)textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector
{
    NSEvent *ev = self.view.window.currentEvent;
    NSLog (@"selector: %s, key: %d", commandSelector, (int)ev.keyCode);
    return NO;
}
```