# Is there a equivalant to textField:shouldReplaceCharactersInRange for NSTextField?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield, nstextview

I want to catch the input text in NSTextField before it changes and manipulate it.

like `textField:shouldReplaceCharactersInRange` for `UITextField`, and 
`textView:shouldChangeTextInRange` for `NSTextView`.

Update:
I don't mind if `textDidChange(notification: NSNotification)` will be triggered or not

Comment: Read about [the field editor](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextFieldsAndViews/TextFieldsAndViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009459-CH8-BBCFEBHA).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to intercept keystrokes from within the field editor of an NSTextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901733/how-to-intercept-keystrokes-from-within-the-field-editor-of-an-nstextfield)

Comment: Or add a custom formatter, a subclass of `NSFormatter`, and implement `isPartialStringValid:proposedSelectedRange:originalString:originalSelectedRange:errorDescription:`.

Comment: `NSTextField` is a subclass of `NSControl` which has a `validateEditing` method. Maybe that can help you.

Answer (score 1):

When your `NSTextField` is focused, it becomes the delegate of an `NSTextView` known as a "field editor". As a result, your `NSTextField` can conform to the `NSTextViewDelegate` protocol, which means you can implement [`textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementString:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextviewdelegate/1449325-textview?language=objc) like so:

```
@interface MyTextField : NSTextField <NSTextViewDelegate>
@end

@implementation MyTextField

- (BOOL)textView:(NSTextView *)textView 
  shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)affectedCharRange 
  replacementString:(NSString *)replacementString
{
  // Do your thing.
}

@end
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet var textField: NSTextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        textField.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: NSTextFieldDelegate {

    func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: Notification) {
        if let textField = obj.object as? NSTextField {
            NSLog("%@", textField.stringValue)
            // how about set the textField's max length
            textField.stringValue = String(textField.stringValue.prefix(6))
        }
    }
}
```